# Ubuntu not recognizing iPhone

Tags: usb, iphone

I know there are ALOT of these questions that have been asked, and solved. But I followed those I found, and for me, neither of them worked for me! ifuse won't detect my iPhone!

A few days ago I could access my iPhone just normally, but now, it doesn't work! :(

Here are some specs:

```
iPhone (before) :
```

Model : iPhone 4

iOS Version : iOS 6.0

Jailbroken? : Yes

Using stand/dock? : No

```
iPhone (after) :
```

Model : iPhone 4

iOS Version : iOS 6.0.1

Jailbroken? : No

Using stand/dock? : Yes

```
Computer:
```

Model : Mac Mini (mid-2009)

Ubuntu Version : 10.04 Lucid

USB-Ports : 5

And yes, I have tested to empty all used USB's expect for the iPhone's charging cable and I have tested with the original Apple USB cable

Oh, and by the way, I tried with my sisters iPhone 3G and it worked just fine!

And still no difference!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.

I have an iphone 4. 2 days ago it was using IOS 4 and I could mount the internal memory on my Ubuntu Oneiric PC. I upgraded my iphone to IOS 6 and now my PC will no longer mount my iphone.  Theres no error. dmesg just has ::

```
[23249.171564] usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device number 18 using ehci_hcd
[23249.386535] ipheth 2-1.2:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
[23249.436087] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
```

So basically, my Ubuntu sees the phone, thinks it's an ethernet device and therefore cannot mount the disk space like it did before. Nothing I try will work. Any suggestions?

I've got the following software installed on my PC ::

```
libimobiledevice-dev
libimobiledevice-utils
libimobiledevice2
```

I've also tried ::

```
sudo idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the commands you listed, sadly none of them work. I've tried looking around the internet for answers, but they only work for iOS 4 <.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is iOS 6. You WILL NOT be able to sync music. I know that's not what you asked, but I think it doesn't hurt to make people aware of that.

Having said that, iOS 5 made it hard to mount the iPhone on Linux, and iOS 6 made it nearly impossible. Some systems can mount, some can't, and some (like mine) mount the three file systems for five minutes and then unmount two of them. I had iTunes working on a WinXP virtual machine, but when I upgraded to iOS 6.1.3 everything stopped working altogether.

Sorry, this answer is NOT a solution, but at least it's a hint on what it would possibly be the problem.

< rant > That's why my next phone will be Android-based... < / rant >

Comment: Yeah, I thing I'll be switching to an android phone next to..., Apple just want to keep Linux out of the way, well thanx for the answer anyway

Comment: After I answered you, I started fiddling with it again and found out that MAYBE this is not entirely iOS 6 fault. More on that:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/289657/ubuntu-13-04-mounts-iphone-disk-spaces-and-after-a-while-unmounts-them