# Ubuntu 13.04 mounts iPhone disk spaces and after a while unmounts them

Tags: mount, 13.04, iphone, itunes

iPhone 4, iOS 6.1.3, Ubuntu 13.04

On 12.10 and before, I could mount my iPhone without problems. Ubuntu mounted automagically two "shares", "iPhone" and "Documents on iPhone", and you can access your files there. If you setup iTunes on a Windows virtual machine, you can even sync your music!

BUT... on version 13.04, Ubuntu mounts THREE iPhone "shares", the previous two and another one called "Internal Storage", which points to the DCIM photo directory. The thing is, after a while (~5min), everything is unmounted except this "Internal Storage".

For what I have been reading and testing, it seems like systemd is killing usbmuxd because it runs as root. The old SysV init didn't have a problem with that. If you run usbmuxd manually and as root (sudo) the thing works.

Any one experiencing the same behaviour?

Comment: I haven't had this experience but the only time I really plug my phone into my computer is for a quick charge (when I don't have the  wall plug handy) I do everything else over the cloud...

Comment: How can you sync music over the cloud?

Comment: If you buy your music via iTunes they have this functionality build in... other wise you can use a service like Amazon MP3 Cloud Player, or Google Music to stream your music...

Comment: I have exactly the same behaviour and it's really annoying.

Comment: Yes but that way you can't use the music app to listen to music. You have to rely on third party apps that are kind of lacking. (For instance, only Apple's Music App have access to the internal equalizer).

Comment: I had the same problem on my home 13.04 PC. When I moved the USB cable from the low power front port to the rear port _voila_, no more unmounting

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 13.04 what worked for me with an iPhone 4 and ios 7 is to use a USB3.0 jack.
The USB jacks on the front of a PC are typically 2.0, I could not connect using them.